# Short if with typeof gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, typeof

The following code:

```
var isBlacklisted = (typeof item.is_blacklisted == "undefined" ? false : true);
console.log(typeof item.is_blacklisted == "undefined");
console.log(isBlacklisted);
```

outputs:

`false
 true`

No matter if `is_blacklisted` is actually `undefined` or not, in both cases it's always same results.

Now I also tried doing:

- `var isBlacklisted = typeof item.is_blacklisted == "undefined" ? false : true;`
- `var isBlacklisted = (typeof item.is_blacklisted == "undefined" ? false : true);`
- `var isBlacklisted = (typeof item.is_blacklisted === "undefined" ? false : true);`

And had the exact same results. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong there, any insights?
**PLEASE CHECK OUT FIDDLE**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dT8Cr/1/)

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I think you mean: `var isBlacklisted = (typeof item.is_blacklisted == "undefined" ? true : false);`

Comment: no I dont... is typeof is undefined that means he is not blacklisted...

Comment: They _are_ giving [different results](http://jsfiddle.net/2xfV8/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result right after the `?` is what you get if your **condition** is true. Since your condition is indeed true, the ternary operator results in false. In order to get it working, just swap `true` and `false` on your ternary:

```
var isBlacklisted = (typeof item.is_blacklisted == "undefined" ? true : false)
```

Or don't even use a ternary in first place, since you're working with booleans:

```
var isBlacklisted = typeof item.is_blacklisted == "undefined"
```

## EDIT

I just checked your fiddle and I see you're setting your attribute to `null`, which is **not the same thing as undefined**. `typeof null` returns `object`, not `undefined`. . This may be the reason of your confusion. If you set it as `undefined` instead of `null`, you'll get the result you want.

Comment: but that's NOT the case! if is_blacklisted is undefined it means that that he is NOT blacklisted, so it should be false. It's the same result whether it's undefined or not same results

Comment: See the edit. Why do you need to check the typeof the property anyway? If it's set to anything, it won't be undefined. You should use a boolean instead.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your problem.
In your fiddle, you're defining item.is_blacklisted as null. Since null isn't the same as undefined, your expression evaluates to false. That's how it works:

```
var a = (condition ? result if condition is true : result if condition is false);
```

Your fiddle outputs false and true, which is correct. IF I change null to undefined, the console outputs true and false.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wanna test comparison by using string "undefined" or with undefined JavaScript property?

Test if a variable is undefined:

```
var x;

if (x === undefined) {
    txt = "x is undefined";
} else {
    txt = "x is defined";
}
```

The result of txt will be:

```
x is undefined
```

The undefined property indicates that a variable has not been assigned a value.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp